# Why can't an implemented method be static?

Tags: java

I am creating a program in which there are various classes that convert the dollar to and from various different currencies. For example, a class for Yen, a class for Euro, etc. Each class implements the interface `Converter`, which contains the methods `toDollar()` and `fromDollar()`.

```
interface Convert {
    double fromDollar(double dollars);
    double toDollar(double otherCurrency);
    double dollar = 1.1; //each euro is 1.1 dollar
}
```

However, I am trying to implement these methods as `static`, because I should not need an instance of the class in order to convert from dollars. However, I am receiving an error when I try to implement/override these methods in the interface. How should I go about this?

```
public class toEuro implements Convert{

    private final double euro = .91;

    public double fromDollar(double dollars){
        return dollars * euro;
    }
    public double toDollar(double euro){
        return euro / dollar;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        toEuro tE = new toEuro();
        System.out.println(toE.fromDollar(12833.23));
    }

}
```

**I do not want to make an instance of toEuro! I should just be able to access it statically.**

Comment: If you only want to access it via static methods, what is the point of your `Convert` interface?  How were you expecting to invoke the methods exactly?

Comment: "However, I am receiving an error" - And you don't think the error is relevant to the question?

Comment: Why even use an interface then if there's to be no inheritance. The question makes no sense.

Comment: The OP wants to use static methods, but also wants to enforce an interface.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: but to what purpose?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Should be using a different Pattern I think

Comment: `double dollar = 1.1;` in an interface?

Comment: In your code, the methods do not need to be overriden, only the `dollar` value needs to change

Comment: @CommuSoft considering that a variable in an interface is implicitly final, what is the issue with this?

Comment: @jordancolbycox: First of all conceptually: an interface describes *how to interact with an object*, not *how it is implemented*. well in C# it is a problem: generates *"error CS0525: Interfaces cannot contain fields or constants"*. Why is this tagged with [tag:c#]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods aren't inherited and can't be specified by interfaces.  That said, it looks like it might make more sense for `toEuro` not to be a class, but perhaps you should just write `Convert toEuro = new MyConvert(.91)` where `MyConvert` is just a simple implementation with a multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

The point of an Interface in an OOP language is to allow you the usage of diffrent implementations for each instance of the interface.

If all of the methods are to be static, what is the point of having an interface in the first place?